# How to get JSON payload sent by the Slack action message?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, slack

I am trying to build a Slack bot with interactive buttons. I have set up a Google Apps Script to handle the action performed on the Slack message. I want the payload of the request sent by the Slack. I have tried to get the request object by doing

```js
function doPost(e) {
    return processComment(e);
}
function processComment(e) {
    Logger.log(e);
}
```

`{postData=FileUpload, queryString=method=slack, parameter={method=slack, payload={"type":"block_actions","user":{"id":"U01835Mxxxx","username":"ravsamteam","name":"ravsamteam","team_id":"T0160UQZZZZ"},"api_app_id":"A018MPZ2xxx","token":"NTNRCTPDz8mxxxzxxxxxxxxx","container":{"channel_id":"C0190D8L2AU","is_ephemeral":false,"message_ts":"1597154895.001500","type":"message"},"trigger_id":"1281039280903.1204976558018.aa1055f6900d7884d9cd4ac34ffzzzzz","team":{"id":"T0160UQGE0J","domain":"ravsamhq"},"channel":{"id":"C0190D8L2AU","name":"blogs"},"message":{"type":"message","subtype":"bot_message","text":"This content can't be displayed.","ts":"1597154895.001500","bot_id":"B019BNL08BS","blocks":[{"type":"section","block_id":"mNavk","text":{"type":"mrkdwn","text":" New comment on RavSam's blog by hello","verbatim":false}},{"type":"section","block_id":"v3Ip","text":{"type":"mrkdwn","text":"*Blog:*\nhello\n\n*Comment:*\nravgeet errorCannot read property 'payload' of undefined","verbatim":false}},{"type":"actions","block_id":"1maVO","elements":[{"type":"button","action_id":"WSo=","text":{"type":"plain_text","text":"Approve","emoji":true},"style":"primary","value":"approved"},{"type":"button","action_id":"Vek\/","text":{"type":"plain_text","text":"Deny","emoji":true},"style":"danger","value":"denied"}]}]},"response_url":"https:\/\/hooks.slack.com\/actions\/T0160Uxxxxx\/1301968xxxxxx\/Q3gZhbeUCUIxxxxxxxxxxxxx","actions":[{"action_id":"WSo=","block_id":"1maVO","text":{"type":"plain_text","text":"Approve","emoji":true},"type":"button","value":"approved","action_ts":"1597213837.152704"}]}}, contentLength=2391.0, parameters={payload=[Ljava.lang.Object;@53f2e9fa, method=[Ljava.lang.Object;@5793298b}, contextPath=}`

How do I get the payload? Once I have the payload JSON, I can use the `actions` to determine what action was taken by the user?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, for example, `e` of `Logger.log(e)` is the values in your question and you want to retrieve `payload` in `parameter`, how about `Logger.log(e.parameter.payload)`? But I'm not sure about the output values you expect. So if this was not the result you expect, can you provide the output values you expect? By the way, I cannot understand the values you expect about `Once I have the payload JSON, I can use the actions to determine what action was taken by the user?`.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike. I was missing this thing. JSON.parse(e.parameter.payload).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The payload contains all the information you need to identify the action. And it also contains a `response_url` to respond back.

Slack payload should look like this.

```javascript
{
    "actions": [
      {
        "name": "channels_list",
        "selected_options": [
          {
          "value": "C012AB3CD"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "callback_id": "select_simple_1234",
    "team": {
      "id": "T012AB0A1",
      "domain": "pocket-calculator"
    },
    "channel": {
      "id": "C012AB3CD",
      "name": "general"
    },
    "user": {
      "id": "U012A1BCD",
      "name": "musik"
    },
    "action_ts": "1481579588.685999",
    "message_ts": "1481579582.000003",
    "attachment_id": "1",
    "token": "iUeRJkkRC9RMMvSRTd8gdq2m",
    "response_url": "https://hooks.slack.com/actions/T012AB0A1/123456789/JpmK0yzoZDeRiqfeduTBYXWQ",
    "trigger_id": "13345224609.738474920.8088930838d88f008e0"
}
```

You can learn more [here](https://api.slack.com/legacy/interactive-messages).